# How to use a static function in Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I would like to have a few objects (e.g. 20 of them), each time I mouse over any one of them, it moves up and each time my mouse leaves, it moves down.

```
obj1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, moveMyself1);
obj1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveMyself2);
obj2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, moveMyself1);
obj2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveMyself2);
obj3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, moveMyself1);
obj3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveMyself2);
obj4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, moveMyself1);
obj4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveMyself2);
obj5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, moveMyself1);
obj5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveMyself2);
//and etc...

function moveMyself1(e:MouseEvent):void{
    obj1.y -= 30;
}

function moveMyself2(e:MouseEvent):void{
    obj1.y += 30;
}
```

I don't want to add an event listener for each of the objects, then I would have 40 methods! Is there any way to write a static method so I can use for all the objects?

And I realized the obj is moving up and down too fast. If you try to put your mouse at the bottom end of the obj, you will see it jumping up n down very fast. Is there any way I can control the speed of the obj?

I wanted to have a few objects in which the user can mouse over and discover treasure underneath. The user can click on the treasure as well. I got this idea from a game. The object will fall back to the same position after the user moves the mouse away. If the object moves too fast, the user can't get to click on the treasure inside. Any idea on how to solve the movement issue?

### Updated

```
var elements : Array = new Array();
var elements2 : Array = new Array();

for (var i:int = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    elements[i] = this['obj' + i];
    elements2[i] = this['tracking' + i];
}

for each(var element_1 : IEventDispatcher in elements){
    element_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, moveUp);  
}

for each(var element_2 : IEventDispatcher in elements2){
    element_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, moveDown);
}

function moveUp(e:MouseEvent):void{
     e.currentTarget.y -= 30;
}

function moveDown(e:MouseEvent):void{
     elements[elements2.indexOf(e.currentTarget)].y += 30;
}
```

Above is my updated code, I tried Richard's suggestion, but it seemed like the objects are moving up and down out of my control.

Comment: It could be the positioning of your tracking layer. Try changing the MOUSE_OVER to be listened on the tracking element, rather than the "obj".

Comment: I followed what u suggested and it seems to work now. I also moved the tracking layer in front of the objects instead. Thx!

Comment: Though my problem is solved now, I still welcome discussion. I learnt a lot from all your ideas combined :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the objects into an array and pass the object from the event handler to your method that applies the logic:

```
var elements : Array = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];

for each(var element : IEventDispatcher in elements)
{
    element.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e:Event) { moveUp(this); } );
    element.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function(e:Event) { moveDown(this); });
}

function moveUp(element : UIElement)
{
    element.y += 30;
}

function moveDown(element : UIElement)
{
    element.y -= 30;
}
```

As far as the movement speed, perhaps you could trigger an animation instead?

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw the "foreach" shld be separated words (It took me some time to figure out cos I am a beginner). I took the combination of ur method and danii's(the one who commented below) method, replaced "function(e:Event) { moveUp(this); }" by "moveUp" and replaced "e.element" by "e.currentTarget"... And it works!

Comment: UPDATED COMMENT: Regarding the movement speed problem it is still not solved. What do u meant by "trigger an animation"? I wanted to have a few objects in which the user can mouse over and discover treasure underneath, haha. The user can click on the treasure as well. I got this idea from a game. The object will fall bck to the same position after the user moves the mouse away. If the obj moves so fast, the user can't get to click on the treasure inside. Any idea on how to solve the movement issue?

Comment: I understand now. Instead of tracking the move over/out on the "rock", use an invisible tracking area in the same position (that doesn't move). That way, the user would have to move the mouse away from the treasure area entirely in order for the "rock" to fall back down.

Comment: By "trigger an animation", I meant start executing a motion tween.

Comment: My updated code is above, but the obj seems to move unexpectedly. What wrong? Sth went wrong with my mouse event? Btw, it seems like if I used a var once in the for loop, I can't it again in the other for loop, tt's why I hv element_1 and element_2. Don't they recognise the var as local variable?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to code a function for each object, since you can refer to the object that is listening to the event as the 'target' of the event, so:

```
function moveUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.y -= 30;
}

function moveDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.y += 30;
}
```

Also, the reason you see the object moving up&down really fast is because when you change the object's position, the mouse stops being inside the object so the MOUSE_OUT event fires, then you change the object's position again to where the mouse is and the MOUSE_OVER event fires and so on. The trace would be:

The object is at y=5 (for example). You move the mouse over (mouse is at y=5). MOUSE_OVER  event fires -> the object moves up (y=35) -> MOUSE_OUT event fires -> the object moves down (y=5) -> since the mouse is still at y=5, MOUSE_OVER event fires -> rinse&repeat.

Please bear in mind that when you set the y of the object, you are not creating a movement animation, but kind of "teletransporting" it to that position.

Comment: UPDATED COMMENT:  
 Your "e.currentTarget" is really very helpful, thank you! The explanation regarding the speed problem is very thoroughly and clear. I wanted to have a few objects in which the user can mouse over and discover treasure underneath, haha. The user can click on the treasure as well. I got this idea from a game. The object will fall bck to the same position after the user moves the mouse away. If the obj moves so fast, the user can't get to click on the treasure inside. Any idea on how to solve the movement issue?

Comment: glad to help... as for the movement problem, the MOUSE_OUT in the object is causing the issue. I would say remove it completely, and in the MOUSE_OVER, insted of 'teletransporting' the object changing its y position, launch a motion tween first up and then down

Comment: Can u explain the motion tween part in more details? I don't get it. When n where shall I put in/call the motion tween? (U may like to take a look at my updated problematic code n comment)

Answer (score 1):

add all the clips you want to listen on to a container:

```
var container:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChild(container);
// rinse and repeat:
container.addChild(objN);
```

Then add an event listener to that container:

```
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleContainerMouseOver } );
container.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, handleContainerMouseOut });

function handleContainerMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.target.y -= 30;
}

function handleContainerMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void{
    e.target.y += 30;
}
```

As a bonus: If you have that many objects named sequentially you can go like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    container.addChild(this['obj' + i]);
}
```

`this['obj' + i]` will resolve to obj1, obj2 and so on.

Comment: Ur "this['obj' + i]" is very useful, thx! How is Sprite better than Array (or other data structure -- which I don't know of)?  I mean why did u recommend Sprite?

Comment: A sprite is like a movieclip but without frames. So it's not really a data structure but rather a way to add your stuff to the display list. Then I make use of something called event bubbling, meaning that the mouse event will first fire for the "child" object clicked, then fire for the parent object (in this case our container sprite) and move it's way up the display list. The major advantage of doing it this way is that you don't need to explicitly listen for on a specific object but rather their wrapper.